# Chainer Iterator for files containing multiple examples without pre-loading

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chainer

I have over 100,000 files containing more than 20 examples per file. The number of samples per file differs. How can I create an iterator with a batch size of ~10 in Chainer without having to pre-load all the files in memory?

Comment: Could you add a worked example to the question?

Comment: I would like to keep it abstract, so it is applicable for more projects and for other people.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `DatasetMixin` class to define your own dataset.
You may override `get_example(i)` method to extract `i`-th data, so you can load the file when you need the data inside `get_example(i)`.
However, it still needs to "pre-indexing", meaning that you need to define which `i`-th data corresponds to which file.

Below are the references how to define own `DatasetMixin` class.

Reference:
 - [Chainer v3 tutorial for beginner (Japanese)](https://qiita.com/mitmul/items/1e35fba085eb07a92560#%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%88%E3%81%86)
 - [Create dataset class from your own data with DatasetMixin](http://corochann.com/create-dataset-class-from-your-own-data-with-datasetmixin-1367.html)

See official example which uses `DatasetMixin` to load the image on-demand:
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/imagenet/train_imagenet.py#L39